# InportError: cannot import 'Node2Vec'

Tags: python, git

I am trying to use node2vec and I can't get past the import section:

```
import networkx as nx
from node2vec import Node2Vec
```

Second line throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node2vec2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from node2vec import Node2Vec
ImportError: cannot import name 'Node2Vec'
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/eliorc/node2vec/issues/21) on the Git repository for the library. I didn't follow everything they were saying but it seemed this was some problem with how the library was installed. So I checked the directory C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages. There is a node2vec folder. The script that's in there is named node2vec.py not Node2Vec.py but changing that on the import statement didn't change anything.

To be certain I'm not running some zombie install I executed python with an explicit path. No help.

Toward the end of that git entry it says

```
Last time I resolved it by cloning the repository and navigating to the code folder and put:
    pip install .
```

And that reportedly fixed it for someone else. But I don't understand what he means by "the code folder." Is that the folder where my script is being run from?

Comment: Could you check that the package itself is installed properly with just `import node2vec`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have `node2vec.py` laying around. Because of this Python tries to import name `node2vec` from it instead of from `site-packages` — and failed.

To check:

```bash
python -c "import node2vec; print(node2vec.__file__)"
```

Rename `node2vec.py` to something different. Never name your scripts the same name as importable modules or packages. For example, never name your scripts `email.py` or `test.py`.